Use Select statements inside NVL function for both arguments
I have the below query where I am trying to use the NVL function in the FROM clause of the SQL statement below, where I have a sub-select statement being used as the first argument, and then a 2nd sub-select statement used for the 2nd argument for when the first statement returns NULL.
When I run this I am getting the ORA-00913: too many values error. Is this happening because the 2nd argument can not be another SQL select expression, and if so do you suggest any alternatives?
SELECT *
FROM   inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD,
       egp_system_items ESI, 
      NVL( --FIRST ARGUMENT OF NVL FUNCTION:
              (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                      ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                      TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) COST_DATE,
                      to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
                  FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                       CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                       CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                 WHERE 1=1
                   AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                   AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID                   
                   AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                   AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                   AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID      
                   AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID             
                 GROUP BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                      ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE
                      ,to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90')
                    
)  ,
    --SECOND ARGUMENT OF NVL FUNCTION:
      (SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
       SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
       '',  
       NVL(to_char((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),'FM99990.90'),LN.UNIT_PRICE) 
            TRANSACTION_COST 
       FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
        ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC
        ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
        ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
        ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM                   
     
       WHERE SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
         AND SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
         AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
         AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
         AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
         AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
         AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
         AND UOM.UOM_CODE(+) = LN.UOM_CODE
         AND INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
         AND SEC.attribute1='Y' ) ) TC
  
 WHERE  1 = 1
   AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
   AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
   AND ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num
    AND TC.subinventory_code(+) = IOQD.subinventory_code
      AND TC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = IOQD.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID  
   
  ) ) 


In that position, a subquery isn't allowed to return more than one row and one column. Move the subqueries to the FROM clause, and LEFT JOIN it.

Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

General tip: use COALESCE instead of NVL, as the former does logic-short-circuiting (i.e. it stops processing at the first non-null value encountered), whereas the latter will evaluate both arguments. Doesn't really matter if the second arguement is a literal, but performance could be improved if the second argument is a function/query.

It was working previously without the NVL if I wrapped both expressions in SELECT * FROM...(expression 1, expression 2)

(although I agree with Jarlh, using NVL/COALESCE isn't the right approach for your problem)

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: a minimal example of the problem (i.e. if you can reduce the table to 3 tables with a few columns then do that rather than using 12 tables); the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment you have syntactically invalid code with no explanation as to what you logic you actually want or what the expected output would be which makes it hard to propose a solution.

"when the first statement returns NULL" - it won't. The statement returns four columns (inventory_item_id, c.subinventory_code, cost_date, transaction_cost), so it cannot return a single NULL. It could return (null, null, null, null), but NVL only works on single data types, not on compound ones, so you get a syntax error.

NVL (and COALESCE) are used in the SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY or ORDER BY clauses, not the FROM clause.
LEFT OUTER JOIN your two sub-queries in the FROM clause and then use COALESCE (or NVL) to get the relevant priority data in the SELECT clause:
Something like:
SELECT IOQD.*,
       ESI.*,
       COALESCE(tc1.COST_DATE, tc2.COST_DATE) AS COST_DATE,
       COALESCE(tc1.TRANSACTION_COST, tc2.TRANSACTION_COST) AS TRANSACTION_COST
FROM   inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD
       INNER JOIN egp_system_items ESI
       ON     IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
          AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                 C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                 TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) COST_DATE,
                 to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
         FROM    CST_ONHAND_V A
                 INNER JOIN CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B
                 ON     A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID                   
                    AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                    AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                    AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                 INNER JOIN CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                 ON     A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID
         WHERE   A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
         GROUP BY
                 A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                 C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                 to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90')
                    
       ) TC1
       ON     TC1.subinventory_code = IOQD.subinventory_code
          AND TC1.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = IOQD.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                NULL AS cost_date,  
                NVL(
                  to_char((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),'FM99990.90'),
                  LN.UNIT_PRICE
                ) AS TRANSACTION_COST 
         FROM   INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
                INNER JOIN inv_secondary_inventories SEC
                ON     SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
                   AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
                INNER JOIN PO_LINES_ALL LN
                ON LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
                ON HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM
                ON     UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                   AND UOM.UOM_CODE = LN.UOM_CODE
         WHERE  SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
         AND    HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
         AND    INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
         AND    SEC.attribute1='Y'
       ) TC2
       ON     TC2.subinventory_code = IOQD.subinventory_code
          AND TC2.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = IOQD.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
WHERE  ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num

Or, maybe if you want to prioritise one table over the other then:
SELECT *
FROM   inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD
       INNER JOIN egp_system_items ESI
       ON     IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
          AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                COST_DATE,
                TRANSACTION_COST,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                               SUBINVENTORY_CODE
                  ORDER BY priority
                ) AS rnk
         FROM   (
           SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                  C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                  TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) COST_DATE,
                  to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST,
                  1 AS priority
           FROM   CST_ONHAND_V A
                  INNER JOIN CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B
                  ON     A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID                   
                     AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                     AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                     AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                  INNER JOIN CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                  ON     A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID
           WHERE  A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
           GROUP BY
                  A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                  C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                  to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90')
         UNION ALL
           SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
                  SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                  NULL AS cost_date,  
                  NVL(
                    to_char((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),'FM99990.90'),
                    LN.UNIT_PRICE
                  ) AS TRANSACTION_COST,
                  2 AS priority
           FROM   INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
                  INNER JOIN inv_secondary_inventories SEC
                  ON     SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
                     AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
                  INNER JOIN PO_LINES_ALL LN
                  ON LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                  INNER JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
                  ON HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM
                  ON     UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                     AND UOM.UOM_CODE = LN.UOM_CODE
           WHERE  SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
           AND    HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
           AND    INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
           AND    SEC.attribute1='Y'
         )
       ) TC
       ON     TC.subinventory_code = IOQD.subinventory_code
          AND TC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = IOQD.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
          AND TC.rnk = 1
WHERE  ESI.inventory_item_id = :p_inv_num

(Note: Both untested as we do not have your tables or sample data and do not know what output you expect.)
